# Ignore null values in insert queryin mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I receive data that may contain null values, I want to ignore them and only insert values that are not NULL for Example:

```
INSERT INTO student 
   (`id`, `age`, `last_value`)
 VALUES
   (1,21,3),
   (2,25,null),
   (3,23,9);
```

here I want to ignore the null value in the second row to avoid making it overriding the last value collected before.

Comment: How come you need to worry about previous value when you are inserting a row?

Comment: it is actually INSERT using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. sorry if it is not clear enough.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify exactly what you need to do, otherwise it is impossible for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you’re getting the query built, it’s hard to give you a definitive answer. But you can check where you’re getting the values from and inserting them into the query, and just don’t create a row if any of the values are `null`.

Comment: I need the values of the other columns so i can't ignore the raw

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle it in context of insert statement then make column not null.  Now insert attempt will fail with specific error code.  You can handle that in client code.

This will work if execution context is where one row is added at a time